# One Login Open ID Connect workflow, how to enable Duo Security MFA

Tags: onelogin

Currently we have Open ID Connect auth workflow with One Login working just fine and able to log users in via custom stand application without browsers (custom UI). Now the requirement came in to enable MFA via Duo Security.
We have enabled the Duo Security Authentication Factor on One Login side of things and when user logs in via browser it works as expected => user can select "Send me a Push". Now we need to achieve the same workflow programattically:

1. We have followed sample workflow calls outlined here: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/multi-factor-authentication/overview
2. For a given user_id we can retrieve list of enrolled auth factors using version 1 of API => https://{{api-domain}}/api/1/users/{{user_id}}/otp_devices but not version 2 https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/2/users?username=ashley.akua as it returns empty list.
   Sample of response for v1 api call:

```
    "data": {
        "otp_devices": [
            {
                "active": true,
                "auth_factor_name": "Duo Duo Security",
                "needs_trigger": false,
                "type_display_name": "Duo Security",
                "default": true,
                "id": 11223344,
                "user_display_name": "Duo Security"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": {
        "message": "Success",
        "error": false,
        "type": "success",
        "code": 200
    }
}
```

Now we would like to trigger a push notification for Duo Security MFA:

Given that "need_trigger" is set to false we call verify directly with no state_token or otp_token in body => https://api.us.onelogin.com}/api/1/users/999999/otp_devices/11223344/verify

we get the following:

```
{
    "status": {
        "message": "Failed authentication with this factor",
        "error": true,
        "type": "Unauthorized",
        "code": 401
    }
}
```

In both calls I have tried with "Manage All" level of API key

Now the question, how would one trigger a Duo Security push notification from Open ID Connect Password Grant workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer for the benefit of future users:

- First to use Duo via API from OneLogin or AWS for that matter you need to configure Duo on Duo Admin panel as Duo API
- One Login does not support Duo Push auth at this time and only OTP, I am not sure why is that exactly. Using OTP and state_token via create session token
- To answer the main question, Open ID Connect does NOT support MFA at all at this time and specifically Password Grant => in our user case we don't have browser to use so Password Grant is the only option.

We are evaluating alternatives at this time but there is nothing in One Login API that will allow us to move forward at this time